# Running a freshly compiled .NET app reboots machine - how to fix?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-7

- Using Visual Studio 2017, or SharpDevelop 5.1,
- on a somewhat older machine running Windows7 32bit,
- anything I compile that previously worked, even just a new helloworld, i.e. - any built Winforms C#.NET 4.x program,
- will, when attempting to run, **instantly hard-reboot** the machine, no prisoners taken.

I had that a year ago or some more already, and don't compile things often on that old laptop. I would have thought that updates would have "magically" solved this by now, but not so.

Also, I would have thought this should be a known problem by now, esp. on MS forums - but I find absolutely zero, and it seems not easy to find a search term combination that will not yield a million hits on topics that aren't this.

**Added:**

- The insta-BSOD/reboot apparently only happens when I start the .NET program out of a **debugger**
- if I start the supposed .NET executable out of windows explorer, I get a dialog with the caption "16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem", and main text: "The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction". As if the thing does not recognize it's a .NET app?
- .NET executables built a year ago on this machine still work just fine right now on this very machine. Only newly built stuff seems to have this problem

But I reckon *somebody* besides me has seen this problem.

What leads to this problem, what fixes it?

Comment: What does Windows event log tell you?

Comment: So I crashed the machine again using the outlined procedure. The system event log contains an error that says the system was unexpectedly rebooted without proper shutdown - but there are no errors close by to the timestamp, also not under applications.
I'll add some extra info I noticed in a minute, to the OP